# std::vector destructor gives error

Tags: c++, class, memory, vector, destructor

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {};

    ~Foo() {};

    void MyFunc(int a)
    {
        m_struct.my_vec.push_back(a);
    }

public:
    MyStructType m_struct;
}
```

and MyStructType is defined similar to this:

```
struct MyStructType
{
    std::vector<int> my_vec;
}
```

The problem is that when I instantiate the class as follows, I get a memory violation error for std::vector deallocation when the m_struct destructor is called:

```
void main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.m_struct.my_vec.push_back(10);
}
```

However, if I do it the following way, the result is the same, but I don't get any error:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.MyFunc(10);
}
```

To me, the two methods should be identical. Given that the actual code is more complicated than the snippet above, I would prefer to make m_struct public and go with the first option. Any suggestions as why the first method gives error when vector is being deallocated?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I notices that the problem is in fact in dll_export, which I failed to mention above. I am generating a dll and using it in another project. If I drop dllexport and put the definitions of the functions (although empty) in the header file, it runs OK. But when I export my class and put the definitions in the cpp file, it is when it gives me the error. Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably corrupting memory somewhere in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: With simple implementations of `Foo::Foo()` and `Foo::~Foo()`, I was able to run both methods without any problem.

Comment: I have only std::vector. No pointers at all, and I am not doing anything weird with the vector indices. So I am not sure how memory corruption could happen.

Comment: Could there be a problem with my constructor as I just added above?

Comment: Why in the world are you zero'ing m_struct in your Foo constructor? You just messed up (read: corrupted) the entire std::vector in the struct and undid the work of the vector constructor.

Comment: I was attempting to initialize all the members of m_struct to zero. I just removed the memset, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you doing something similar in your MyStructType constructor?

Comment: No. I have not defined any cons/destructors for MyStrustType.

Comment: Are you using memset or something similar elsewhere with f or f.m_struct etc.?

Comment: No other memset, pointers, new or delete. Thanks..

Comment: I notices that the problem is in fact in dll_export, which I failed to mention above. I am generating a dll and using it in another project. If I drop dllexport and put the definitions of the functions (although empty) in the header file, it runs OK. But when I export my class and put the definitions in the cpp file, it is when it gives me the error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to give us an actual SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/) - a minimal version of the code of both your DLL and your other project that can compile but produces the error you are seeing. Otherwise we are all just guessing around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you use dll_export, the cause of corruption can be one or more of the following:

- The application and DLL were not compiled with the same compiler options in terms of code generation.
- The application and DLL are using different heaps at runtime.

For the first item, you must make sure that the compiler options such as structure packing, and any other option that will change the class's internals in some way, are the same.  But even more basic, the app and DLL must be compiled with the same version of the compiler.

For the second item, you must make sure that the application and DLL use the same heap.  To do this, both the DLL and app must use the DLL version of the runtime library.

When you have a class that handles dynamically allocated memory such as `std::vector` passing and using these class across module boundaries become error prone.  Note that the problem is not `std::vector`, as any class, even one that you would have written, would have the same issue if the class uses the heap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the dll and main under the same project tree; so same compiler. I realized that my std::vector did not have a DLL interface. So I implemented what was suggested in here: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;168958
Actually worked!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line :
memset(&m_struct, 0, sizeof(m_struct);

It likely corrupts the vector in MyStructType. Why are you doing that ?

Comment: *likely*, more like definitely.

Comment: I did remove that memset, but the problem persists. Please see the UPDATE I added at the bottom of the question. Any ideas why dllexport may be problematic here?