# Passing std::vector by reference to Exported Member Function using MSVC 2013 and 2015, Using CMake and ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, dllexport

I have a dynamic library that builds in both Linux and Windows. When running my unit tests against the static libraries under both systems I have no issues. When running my unit tests against my shared library in linux everything works just fine. My issue arrises when running my unit tests against the shared library in Windows.

In short my stack trace is the following:

```
UnitTest.exe!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1424    C++
UnitTest.exe!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1265   C++
UnitTest.exe!operator delete(void * pUserData) Line 54  C++
UnitTest.exe!std::allocator<QuadKey::QuadKey>::deallocate(QuadKey::QuadKey * _Ptr, unsigned __int64 __formal) Line 574  C++
UnitTest.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<QuadKey::QuadKey> >::deallocate(QuadKey::QuadKey * _Ptr, unsigned __int64 _Count) Line 859 C++
UnitTest.exe!std::vector<QuadKey::QuadKey,std::allocator<QuadKey::QuadKey> >::_Tidy() Line 1629 C++
UnitTest.exe!std::vector<QuadKey::QuadKey,std::allocator<QuadKey::QuadKey> >::~vector<QuadKey::QuadKey,std::allocator<QuadKey::QuadKey> >() Line 946    C++
UnitTest.exe!QuadKey::BINGSYSTEM_GetChildren_Test::TestBody() Line 195  C++
```

The exported member functions that are called in the body of `QuadKey::BINGSYSTEM_GetChildren_Test::TestBody()` take a reference to an array, pass it to a non-exported function in anthor class and return. Such as below.

```
void QuadKey::getChildren(std::vector<QuadKey> &outKeys) const
{
    m_Impl->getChildren(outKeys, (*this));
}
```

--

```
// m_Impl getChildren System class is not exported.
void System::getChildren(std::vector<QuadKey> &outKeys,
    const QuadKey &self) const
{
    for (std::uint8_t quadrant = 0; quadrant < 4; ++quadrant) {
        QuadKey child =
          getChild(static_cast<QuadKey::Quadrant>(quadrant), self);
        Detail::insertVectorIfValidAndUnique(outKeys, child);
    }
}
```

Is it safe to assume that this practice is not standard when using MSVC? That is passing in a `std::vector` into a exported funcntion? If not what should I be assuming here? The assert happens when the vector goes to be free'd as it goes out of scope from the unit test body. I have tried to call clear on the vector but the same crash occurs even on an empty `std::vector`.

---

**AMMENDMENT:**

After changing my UnitTest and Dynamic library to use MD (MDd for debug) instead of MT (MTd for debug) I get an error:

```
Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj  UnitTest    C:\Users\mehoggan\Devel\QuadKeys\build\UnitTest\libcpmtd.lib(StlCompareStringA.obj) 1
```

This is because gtest by default is compiled with static linking against the Standard Runtime. Say I did not want to change gtest what would be good C++ practice when writing interfaces that need standard containers passed across dll boundaries?

Comment: Are you linking to the static CRT or the DLL version?  There are issues when statically linking to the CRT in both the DLL and EXE.

Comment: I am not 100% sure. CMake is generating my vcxproj files. Where can I look to find this information for you? Better asked which page in the projects configuration properties should I be looking at to verify this?

Comment: Are you building the DLL and its user with the same compiler and CRT? If you can't guarantee this it is _hard_ to use `vector` in a DLL interface [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/VisualStudio/warningC4251.html) is an nice (albeit old) read on the topic

Comment: @MatthewHoggan I'm not familiar with CMake, but I just realized that your are because the stack trace shows the _free_dbg function in your EXE and not the CRT DLL.

Comment: Please see this, and read the last paragraph:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312603/dll-works-fine-in-a-vs2010-project-but-gives-access-violations-in-a-vs6-applicat/25313163#25313163 and this possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174476/stdvector-destructor-gives-error/23176123#23176123

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are statically linking to the C Runtime.  You need to link with the DLL version.  Build with `/MD`, not `/MT`.

See [Potential errors passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235460%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for problems this can cause.

Comment: I have made CMake to set the Runtime Library to use dynamic linking. However in doing so, it has producted another set of errors since gtest is configured. I have updated my post to reflect a better understood problem.